# python Dataframe difference giving wrong values

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have two dataframes, prices and pricesOld. Having columns OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE.
When I subtract two columns,why does it gives wrong values?

prices["diff"]=pricesOld["CLOSE"]-prices['CLOSE']

prices OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE respectively//:`23.80    22.00   23.15   22.75`

pricesOld OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE respectively://`23.0  23.0    22.55   22.7    22.6`

but the resulting diff gives value:65761.70

Comment: There seems to be an extra column in your PricesOld. Is that an index or a typo? Additionally, when I run the script, it outputs the -0.15, as I expect. Are you sure there's not some indexing problem?